# Prove or disprove that the set of even integers forms a group under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

possible duplicate but want work checked and verified

let $l =$ any even number and $m =$ any even number

$l+m = w$ where $w$ is any element in the even integers thus it is closed under addition

$2k+0=2k$ and $0-2k=2k$ so there is an identity both left and right

every even number can have its negative added to get 0 so there is an inverse for every element in the even integers i.e $2+(-2)=0$

Its associative

Comment: did you mean $0-2k$ where you wrote $0+2k$, and did you mean $w$ is *an* element in the even integers (it would be nice to provide justification of that)?

Comment: Are you quite sure that $0-2k=2k$? Do note that you never defined what $k$ is. Additionally, is $w$ really _any_ even integer? I'm not sure that $2+2=10$. For verifying that inverses exists, you assumed the axiom in your proof. What you need to do is _prove_ that if $n$ is an even integer, then $-n$ is also even and is the inverse of $-n$.

Comment: well it equals -2k = -1(2)k=2(-k) and 2 times any number is an even number

Comment: @K.Gibson That is precisely the type of logic that is missing from each of the statements in your question.

Comment: Okay I see where it could clarified in my steps

Comment: 1) "l+m=w where w is any element in the even integers thus it is closed under addition"  This is correct but badly stated, it's almost incoherent. Better to phrase it "If $l, m$ are even then $l+m$ will also be even (wouldn't hurt to prove that) so addition is closed".  2) $0 - 2k \ne 2k$.  $0+2k = 2k$. 3)  addition is associative in $\mathbb R$ so it is associative for any subset of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is okay, but it can be improved.

**Closed:** For any $l,m \in \mathbb{E}$ (where $\mathbb{E}$ is the set of even integers) $l = 2a$ and $m = 2b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $l + m = 2a + 2b = 2(a+b) \in \mathbb{E}$.

**Identity:** $0 \in \mathbb{E}$ and $0 + m = m + 0 = m$ for all $m \in \mathbb{E}$.

**Inverse:** For any $2k \in \mathbb{E}$, the number $2(-k) \in \mathbb{E}$ and $2k + 2(-k) = 2k - 2k = -2k + 2k = 0$.

**Associative:** The integers under addition are associative, so $\mathbb{E} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ inherits that property.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is fine.

Here's a more general result.

> **Theorem:** For $k\in \Bbb Z,$ we have $$k\Bbb Z\le \Bbb Z.$$

*Proof:* Let $k\in \Bbb Z$. We use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test); that is, we show that $\emptyset\neq k\Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb Z$ and for any $m,n\in k\Bbb Z$, written additively, $m-n\in \Bbb Z$.

Indeed, $0=k0\in k\Bbb Z$, so $k\Bbb Z$ is nonempty. Let $\ell\in k\Bbb Z$. Then $\ell=kt$ for some $t\in \Bbb Z$, so $\ell$ is an integer as $k, t\in\Bbb Z$. Thus $k\Bbb Z\subseteq \Bbb Z$.

Let $m, n\in k\Bbb Z$. Then $m=ka, n=kb$ for some $a, b\in\Bbb Z$. But now $m-n=ka-kb=k(a-b)$ and $a-b\in\Bbb Z$. Hence $m-n\in k\Bbb Z$.

Hence $k\Bbb Z \le \Bbb Z$. $\square$

Now just let $k=2$ in the theorem above.

Comment: Why the downvote?